# Gentoo, reconfigure network after changing network interface name from eno1 to sit0, fresh install

Tags: networking, gentoo, network-interface

I'he just install Gentoo. After boot I recognized that I don't have an internet connection. 
Using

```
ls -l /sys/class/net
```

I've found that **eno1** was changed to **sit0**

How to reconfigure network after changing network interface name from **eno1** to **sit0**, fresh install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [gentoo networking documentation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Full/Networking), it seems you will have to add an entry into `/etc/conf.d/net` for 'sit0'.

For DHCP:

```
config_sit0="dhcp"
```

For static IP (replace with correct values):

```
config_sit0="192.168.0.7/24"
routes_sit0="default via 192.168.0.1"
dns_servers_sit0="192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8"
```

Now to start the interface with the new configuration, from the terminal:

```
/etc/init.d/net.sit0 start
```

And to enable on startup:

```
rc-update add net.sit0 default
```